# Viewing gtag Custom Events Data in Reports

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

I have setup the [new gtag custom event tracking code](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events#custom-events-and-parameters) and it appears to be creating events as I see the previous category, action, and labels appearing under **Events > Top Events**. HOWEVER **I can't figure out where I can view my "custom" parameters** I have specified. For example, I am also recording "link_Text" and "time_taken" parameters on events.

```
gtag('event', category, {
  "event_category": category,
  "event_action": action,
  "event_label": label,
  "link_Text" : linkText,
  "time_Taken": time_taken,
});
```

Comment: Have you mapped your custom parameters to an index in the config part of the tag (and did you remember to create the dimensions in GA in the first place) ? Then you should be able to select them as secondary dimensions and use them in custom reports, segments, or via the API. They are not part of the standard reports.

Comment: I think I am missing these parts as I did not see anything that references these steps on the Event Tracking docs page. I believe this is what your referring to that needs setup as well https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets along with https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en